# Add Title in popup window

Tags: android, popup

I want to add a header in `popup` window which should be fixed over popup list. Only popup list should be `scroll`. how can i do this? Please suggest me.

```
public PopupWindow popupWindowcountry() {

    PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(this);

    ListView listView = new ListView(this);

    listView.setAdapter(Country_Padpter);
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setWidth((int) (getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getWidth() / 2.2));

    popupWindow.setHeight(515);

    popupWindow.setContentView(listView);
    return popupWindow;
}

private class PopupWindows_Adpter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Country_arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) DNPActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new View(DNPActivity.this);
            convertView = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.country_popup_row, null);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.item_txt_popup_row);
            final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.popup_ll);
            // final TextView header=(TextView)
            // convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_txt_popup_header);
            textView.setText(Country_arrayList.get(position).getName());
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textView.setTextSize(18);
            textView.setPadding(15, 10, 10, 10);
            layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String selectedtext = textView.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(DNPActivity.this, selectedtext,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    country_selected_txt = selectedtext;

                    tvtotalnewspapernumber.setText(country_selected_txt);
                    popupWindowcountry.dismiss();
                    new FilterAsync().execute();
                }
            });
        } else {
            convertView = (View) convertView;
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `addHeaderView` to add title for ListView

Answer (score 1):

ListPopupWindow has a couple calls from API 11 onward.

```
void setPromptView(View prompt)
void setPromptPosition(int position)
```

These will add a custom view above or below the list view but not both at the same time. The view will not be affected by the list view scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

> add a header in popup window which should be fixed over popup list

You can achive same by adding Header for ListView which is inside PopUpWindow. do it as:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("your title text here");
listView.addHeaderView(tv);
```

Or you can also use custom layout for HeaderView see following tutorial :

[Listview with header footer view android](https://blograchita.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/listview-with-header-footer-view-android/)

Comment: I allready aaplied this...but that text is also scrolling in listview. while i need to fix  it. only popup list should be scroll not that text header.